# Show facebook image using user id in html page

Tags: php, html

Here is my img tag to show img

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/"+<?php echo $user_id; ?>+"/picture?type = small">   ..[x]
```

user_id is php variable that I receive here on top of the code:

```
<?php
    $user_id = $_POST['userid'];
?>
```

what is error in like [x]? it does not show the image

Answer (score 1):

Ok got it.

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user_id; ?>/picture?type = small">
```

works